# Calculating limits of trigonometric functions analytically

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I am trying to figure out how to solve a certain set of problems using the trigonometric identities for evaluating limits, which are:

- $\displaystyle \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}=1$
- $\displaystyle \lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\cos\theta-1}{\theta}=0$

How can I apply these identities to the following problems? I am confused as to the actual calculus used to solve them. Also, I have just started calculus and I do not know any other rules to solve them with, such as L'Hopital's rule, which I have only heard the name of, and I have not gotten to that point in the class yet.

1. $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^2x}{x}$
2. $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan^2x}{x}$
3. $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pi/2 } \frac{\cos x}{\cot x}$
4. $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \pi /4} \frac{1-\tan x}{\sin x-\cos x}$
5. $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sin 3t}{2t}$

Thanks!

Comment: If $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = a$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = b$, then  $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x) = ab$. So, for example, for 1., take $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ and $g(x) = \sin x$.

Comment: "these identities"...what identities are you talking about?

Comment: @copper.hat I'm still a little confused by how that works out for #1. How could you solve for the limit with that information?

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm referring to the special trigonometric limits (I think that's what they're called). I put them at the top of the question.

Comment: $\frac{\sin^2 x}{x} = \sin x \frac{\sin x}{x}$. You know $\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1$ and $\sin x \to 0$, hence $\frac{\sin^2 x}{x} \to 1\cdot 0 = 0$.

Comment: You did not put identities at the top of the question. You put expressions at the top of the question. Identities need an "$=$" sign. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: @copper.hat Ah, okay, that makes perfect sense. Thanks for the help! Would it be the same concept for the second one?

Comment: @CameronBuie , the second limit of "the identities" is zero...

Comment: @DonAntonio: Yes. I corrected that bonehead mistake (I thought before I posted my edit, but perhaps not).

Comment: Yes, you need to figure out how to 'factor' the expression into the product of two terms whose limits you know.

Comment: @copper.hat Would I expand $\tan^2 x$ to $\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}$ first, or I would I factor $\tan x$ out first before anything?

Comment: Expand $\tan$ as you have done, note that $\cos x \to 1$ and use the result from 1. to finish.

Answer (score 1):

You should also know that, if $s(x)$ converges to $s$, and $t(x)$ converges to $t$, then $s(x)t(x)$ converges to $st$. Similarly, if $s \neq 0$ and $s(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$ (you can restrict attention to $x < \epsilon$) then $t_n/s_n$ converges to $t/s$.

Given this, the first limit can be viewed as

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \lim_{x\to 0} \sin(x) = 1 * 0 = 0$.

Comment: I'm also confused, since the example given is wrong. Also, you have a typo, $t_n/s_n$ converges to $t/s$, provided $s\neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo. Which example are you referring to?

Comment: $\sin(x)/x$ converges to $1$ as $x$ goes to $0$.